# How can I know the data type in graph API response?

Tags: json, facebook, graph

I'm  beginner of graph API. 
For my Application,  I have to use many graph API  at the same time.

My question is...  how can I know  the response's data type?
  => How can I know  the response that it is the friends  data?

ex)  for friend  data. 
   In response data, I can't find  the data name for friend.(== like  friend tag name in XML response)

- request Graph URL 
  = `https://graph.facebook.com/100000726819009/friends`
- response data in graph API  for friends

---

```
{                               
  "data": [                     
    {                           
      "name": "Jong-Mu Choi",   
      "id": "1931865"           
    },                          
    {                           
      "name": "Joo Yeon Kim",   
      "id": "4812863"           
    },                          
    {                           
      "name": "Tommy Kang",     
      "id": "516573995"         
    },                          
    {                           
      "name": "Hyeoniee Jeong", 
      "id": "526059737"         
    },                          
    {                           
      "name": "Sung Park",      
      "id": "528812415"         
    }                           
  ]                             
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola?metadata=1

You will see `type=page` at the bottom.